# rails model with multiple related addresses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, foreign-keys

I have the following rails models:

```
# Address Model
address_line_1
address_line_2
address_line_3
post_code
country

# Vendor model
name
registered_address_id
billing_address_id
display_address_id
```

registered_address, billing_address and display_address should refer to an address in the address table.

so eventually I can do Vendor.registered_address etc.

I am confused about how to go about this with regards to migrations and my relationships on my model, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it declaring explicitly `class_name` on `belongs_to` and `has_many` and `foreign_key` on `has_many`

```
class Vendor < ApplicationModel
  belongs_to :registered_address, class_name: 'Address'
  belongs_to :billing_address, class_name: 'Address'
  belongs_to :display_address, class_name: 'Address'
end

class Address < ApplicationModel
  has_many :registered_addresses, foreign_key: :registered_address_id, class_name: 'Vendor'
  has_many :billing_addresses, foreign_key: :billing_address_id, class_name: 'Vendor'
  has_many :display_addresses, foreign_key: :billing_address_id, class_name: 'Vendor'
end
```

References: -

[has_many](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many)

[belongs_to](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to)

Query =>

```
vendor_object.registered_address
vendor_object.billing_address
vendor_object.display_address
```

Comment: would this require there to be a vendor_id on the address table?

Comment: @Brad No! it's not require unless you want to call `vendor.addresses`. feel free to accept answer if it helped you. also let me know for any further guidance as well, thanks.

Comment: Hi, sorry I havent had a chance to try this yet, will give it a go tonight and accept/respond. Thanks